# Are there any differences in cooking techniques for Farm raised Salmon versus Wild Salmon?

Tags: fish, salmon

In the last couple of months my grocery store has started to sell Farm Raised Salmon and separating it from "Wild" Salmon.  Any difference in cooking these two that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1):

Farmed salmon is often slightly mushier in texture than wild. It also has less depth of flavour. You will want to look for cooking methods that won't add water (grilling, roasting, frying) and have a light hand with the seasoning.

Answer (score 1):

I find the wild salmon to be less fatty and easier to overcook.  I take off a few degrees from final temperature to keep the texture flaky, somewhere between 125-135.

Answer (score 0):

Following up roux's answer (that wild salmon has more flavour, which is true): presumably you'd buy the more expensive wild salmon to enjoy that deeper flavor. One thought is that the deeper flavor will support more additional tastes / seasoning (and it will). Another thought (which I prefer most of the time) is that the deeper flavor should be enjoyed for itself.

So, when cooking the wild salmon, use techniques that preserve the salmon as much as possible 'as it is'. Sashimi, if you're certain of the quality / hygiene, would be the ultimate expression of that.